# Coding challenge: Calculate sum of col values if rows in other col are TRUE (table summary)

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

We have a table where the first col contains values (protein counts) while the following cols are logical vectors (T or F, indicating if protein_id has the property). For each col we seek the sum of all values where col = T and the count of T.

With example data the task might be better to describe:

[please excuse that the example data require a package for the random id generator,
if you know a base R solution please wrote comment and I will include it here].

```
library("stringi")

value <- c(sample(2:5, 20 , replace=T),
           sample(6:10, 20 , replace=T), 
           sample(1:7, 20 ,  replace=T), 
           sample(3:10, 20 , replace=T), 
           sample(10:20, 20 , replace=T) )

data <- data.frame(
  id = stringi::stri_rand_strings(20, 5),
  value = value,
  nucleus = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 20, TRUE),
  membrane = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 20, TRUE),
  mitochondria = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 20, TRUE))
```

For each property col we seek the sum of all values and the count of all ids. Next, check if TRUE in multiple cols. If yes: new col with string of all colnames sep by _ and sum of all values. Lastly a col with all ids sep by ;

```
expected_result_1 <- data.frame(
  property = c('nucleus', 'membrane', 'mitochondria', 'nucleus_ membrane'),
  value_sum = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'w'),
  n_ids = c(4, 3, 1, 2),
  ids = c("MSATv;1NFZ4;Kftq5;JANXo", "htiFJ;kCHtA8;jXXh", "kCHtA", "MSATv_htiFJ"))
```

A dplyr solutions would be great!

Thank you!

Sebastian

Comment: @SteveM This is a clear, reproducible problem, clearly in scope. Homework questions are not off-topic. Questions related to work are not off-topic. I agree, it's nice to see what people have tried, but there are much nicer ways to ask for that. Please try to be more welcoming.

Comment: Hi Steve, that's very harsh. It is a problem I have tried to wrap my head around for quite some time now but I can only solve it with "hard coding" which is a problem for the >100 cols I need to calculate this for. You are right, it is a task of my job but as such it might help to solve the genetic basis of primary immunodeficiencies in children so thanks for contributing if you can ;)

Comment: @SteveM it's fine to ask posters for more detail, to ask them to show work, and attempts. There are nice ways to do that. You are taking an aggressive, unwelcoming, and unhelpful tone that is not in line with Stack Overflow's community guidelines. The first guideline of Stack Overflow's [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) is **Be nice.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether the code below can give the desired output, but here is a base R attempt.

- First, we can define a user function `f`, which helps to summarize the information by properties in `data`

```
f <- function(cols) {
  idx <- rowSums(data[cols]) == length(cols)
  data.frame(
    property = paste0(cols, collapse = "_"),
    value_sum = sum(data$value[idx],na.rm = TRUE),
    n_ids = length(unique(data$id[idx])),
    ids = toString(unique(data$id[idx]))
  )
}
```

- Then, we select the columns (see `v` is the vector of selected column names), and run the following code

```
v <- c("nucleus", "membrane", "mitochondria")
output <- do.call(
  rbind,
  unlist(
    lapply(
      seq_along(v),
      function(k) combn(v, k, FUN = f, simplify = FALSE)
    ),
    recursive = FALSE
  )
)
```

and we will get

```
> output
                       property value_sum n_ids
1                       nucleus       406    11
2                      membrane       367    10
3                  mitochondria       278     8
4              nucleus_membrane       193     5
5          nucleus_mitochondria       135     4
6         membrane_mitochondria       136     4
7 nucleus_membrane_mitochondria        37     1
                                                                          ids
1 zMknh, TUJhp, QVf8L, P5vps, w4NX6, 2IVbG, AT0RG, SxiO7, ErRUg, 1wIAO, YgefT
2        P5vps, w4NX6, nj3Tv, 2IVbG, xRMA3, eZzb4, ErRUg, l9qwa, SQWq3, YgefT
3                      P5vps, QMw74, eZzb4, AT0RG, SxiO7, l9qwa, 1wIAO, SQWq3
4                                           P5vps, w4NX6, 2IVbG, ErRUg, YgefT
5                                                  P5vps, AT0RG, SxiO7, 1wIAO
6                                                  P5vps, eZzb4, l9qwa, SQWq3
7                                                                       P5vps
```

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes, exactly! Thanks for correcting me. I have updated my answer with your helpful feedback

Comment: Hi Thomas, great answer but unfortunately I encounter a problem running it. In the value_sum output I get all NAs. Some ids do not have an entry (in every col F). Might this cause the problem? Otherwise it looks like a superb solution :)

Comment: @SebastianHesse Then you should use `sum(data$value[idx],na.rm = TRUE)`. See my update of function `f`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? (Code below has been edited!)

```
data %<>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -matches("id|value"), names_to = "property", values_to = "is_true")

data %<>% filter(is_true)

data %>% 
  group_by(property) %>%
  transmute(value_sum = sum(value), 
            ids = paste0(id, collapse = ","), 
            n_ids = length(str_split(ids, ","))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct(property, .keep_all = TRUE)

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# property    value_sum ids                                                                                      n_ids
# <chr>           <int> <chr>                                                                                    <int>
#   1 membrane          400 ACiov,3XyaR,z68K4,GaUxZ,YZioV,mEZtJ,J5T67,T6Ine,a33ed,Flgnx,g33vm,ACiov,3XyaR,z68K4,GaU…    55
#   2 nucleus           312 tDCzP,H8DS4,3XyaR,z68K4,YZioV,t8EgQ,Sl9nM,T6Ine,2zgbM,tDCzP,H8DS4,3XyaR,z68K4,YZioV,t8E…    45
#   3 mitochondr…       310 tDCzP,Ey1PM,3XyaR,FWPXg,t8EgQ,T6Ine,ViWyl,2zgbM,g33vm,tDCzP,Ey1PM,3XyaR,FWPXg,t8EgQ,T6I…    45
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I had misunderstood OP's problem. I'm including a solution here that still uses `dplyr` (somewhat) and uses `gtools` to calculate the new column names.

```
library("stringi")
library("stringr")
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")
library("tidyr")
library("gtools")

#Sample data.
value <- c(sample(2:5, 20 , replace=T),
           sample(6:10, 20 , replace=T), 
           sample(1:7, 20 ,  replace=T), 
           sample(3:10, 20 , replace=T), 
           sample(10:20, 20 , replace=T) )

data <- data.frame(
  id = stringi::stri_rand_strings(20, 5),
  value = value,
  nucleus = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 20, TRUE),
  membrane = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 20, TRUE),
  mitochondria = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 20, TRUE))


expected_result_1 <- data.frame(
  property = c('nucleus', 'membrane', 'mitochondria', 'nucleus_ membrane'),
  value_sum = c('x', 'y', 'z', 'w'),
  n_ids = c(4, 3, 1, 2),
  ids = c("MSATv;1NFZ4;Kftq5;JANXo", "htiFJ;kCHtA8;jXXh", "kCHtA", "MSATv_htiFJ"))




#SOLUTION.

#Getting the column names.
cols <- data %>% select(-matches("id|value")) %>% colnames()

#Don't even ask. Suffices to know that generously using lapply() 
#enough times can convert anything into anything.
myfunc <- function(x){
  unique(
    unlist(
      lapply(
        lapply(
          str_split(
            apply(
              gtools::permutations(length(cols), x, v = cols),
              1, paste, collapse = "_"),
            "_"), 
          sort), 
        paste, collapse = "_")
      )
    )
}

#Using the friendly function from above to get all possible 
#combinations of the relevant column names.
newcols <- unlist(lapply(2:length(cols), myfunc))

#Adding these columns to the data.frame and evaluating them conditionally.
#(So if all corresponding individual columns are TRUE, then the new column
#is also TRUE, and FALSE otherwise.)
for(i in 1:length(newcols)){
  #i <- 1
  
  currefs <- unlist(str_split(newcols[i], "_"))
  data[, newcols[i]] <- NA
  data[, newcols[i]] <- eval(parse(text = paste0("data$", currefs, collapse = " & ")))
  
  #for(j in 1:nrow(data)){
  #  data[j, newcols[i]] <- eval(parse(text = paste0("data$", currefs, "[j]", collapse = " & ")))
  #}
  #eval(parse(text = paste0("data$", currefs)))
  
}


#Pivoting longer to gather all these columns together.
data %<>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -matches("id|value"), names_to = "property", values_to = "is_true")

#Retaining only TRUE values.
data %<>% filter(is_true)

#Calculating value_sum, ids, and n_ids.
data %>% 
  group_by(property) %>%
  transmute(value_sum = sum(value), 
            ids = paste0(unique(id), collapse = ","), 
            n_ids = length(unique(unlist(str_split(ids, ","))))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct(property, .keep_all = TRUE)


# # A tibble: 7 x 4
# property                    value_sum ids                                                                      n_ids
# <chr>                           <int> <chr>                                                                    <int>
# 1 nucleus                           472 LpA3Q,2s04A,m1QMR,Lh4HH,wILrx,xKLfq,hUvsn,22cPw,NMTgz,V42mZ,GnJBd,Fwjbr…    13
# 2 membrane                          521 LpA3Q,m1QMR,kYSIh,Lh4HH,CDPr4,wILrx,qAPpb,Zfavp,hUvsn,22cPw,NMTgz,N0RPZ…    14
# 3 mitochondria                      252 LpA3Q,kYSIh,Zfavp,N0RPZ,V42mZ,GnJBd,onM21                                    7
# 4 membrane_mitochondria             182 LpA3Q,kYSIh,Zfavp,N0RPZ,GnJBd                                                5
# 5 membrane_nucleus                  338 LpA3Q,m1QMR,Lh4HH,wILrx,hUvsn,22cPw,NMTgz,GnJBd,Fwjbr                        9
# 6 mitochondria_nucleus              142 LpA3Q,V42mZ,GnJBd,onM21                                                      4
# 7 membrane_mitochondria_nucl…        72 LpA3Q,GnJBd                                                                  2
```

Comment: Thanks Dunois! But your answer made me realise that my example didn't replicate the data, as there the cols all have the same name. Unfortunately, in my data the names are all different. I edited my question to address the issue. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: @SebastianHesse my apologies. I had forgotten to add a couple of crucial lines of code to the solution. I've edited these in now, please take a look. (It wasn't your data's fault, btw).

Comment: Very nice and understandable dplyr coding, thanks! But unfortunately it does not solve the second part with the partial overlaps and that one is a sweet gimmick I was really looking forwards to. It would proteins that are known to change position in the cell so they can be found in several sub cellular locations.

Comment: @SebastianHesse I'm sorry, I had really misunderstood your problem. I've updated my post with a solution (that still uses `tidyverse` in the end). It's not as elegant as the other solution posted here but it should work just as well I think.